# Phonegap online method and window.location

Tags: events, cordova

I'm new to phonegap and I'm still trying to understand the basics.  I want to make a simple app that when it starts up it checks to see if it has an internet connection and if it does I want it to redirect to a website or load that website in the web view.  If it doesn't have an internet connection, then I want it to stay on the app and just display static content.

Here's what I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Online Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
    }

    // Handle the online event example
    //
    function onOnline() {
      window.location.href ="http://google.com";
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

I also set OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to true.

Does the online event only work if the app was offline then gets called when the app goes back online?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, Online event is fired when the app starts if internet is connected and it is also called when the app goes from offline to online mode.

If you want to open a external website in phonegap you can add a child browser plugin for the same Or else you can open a website in a embedded webveiw. window.location.href doesn't work in Phonegap.

I don't know whether you are working on iOS or Android so the link [for iOS](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser) and [for Android](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser)

Answer (score 0):

Move your wiring up of the online event handler (i.e. this line):

```
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
```

up into your onLoad() function. I found that the online/offline events need to be registered on load, rather than later for some reason.

Comment: All the phonegap specific event should be fired after device ready event.